# ExpressJS Nodemon not runnig on server

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, nodemon

I would like to share my apis , and I used Express.js Nodemon on api side. I added my api files on server , but when I open url `http://xxxxx.xxx:3000` , website return to me page not found

I am using plesk onyx on server side

[image]

How can i fix ?

App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/login');
var app = express();


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login', usersRouter);
app.use('/editnotificationtoken', editnotificationtokenRouter);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can you provide some more details ?

Comment: what kind of details?

Comment: your app.js code

Comment: I editted my post

Comment: does your server listen requests on port `3000`?

Comment: I connected server with putty and run nodemon www start in project file. And nodemon started successful